# Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ with $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions

Let $f(x)=\sqrt x$ with $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Discuss the properties of $f$. Is it injective, surjective, bijective, is it a function? Why or why not? Under what conditions change this?

Explain using examples.

I'm having some trouble figuring out this equation.

Comment: Your function is not even well-defined.

Comment: $f$ is not defined on the negative reals, so the function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is ill-defined. However, if you restrict to the positives, i.e. $f:\mathbb R_+\to \mathbb R$ then you're gucci.

Answer (score 1):

You have to restrict the domain and, otherwise $f(x)$ wouldn't be well define for $x \leq 0$ since $\sqrt x$ of a negative number is not well define on $\mathbb{R}$.

$f : \mathbb{R}_{+} \longmapsto \mathbb{R}_{+}$, where $\mathbb{R}_{+} = \left\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R} : x \geq 0 \right\rbrace$

With those assumption it's surjective on $\mathbb{R}_{+}$.

You can see this noticing that $f(0) = 0$, f it's continuos and $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = +\infty$ with positive derivative derivative $f(x)' = \frac{1}{2\sqrt x}$ so $f$ is stricly increasing, hence injective, and invertible.

Comment: I don't think it would be warranted to restrict the codomain to the positives. I would suspect the problem is to identify that $f:\mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R_+$ is surjective whereas $f:\mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R$ is not.

Comment: And I don’t think that check derivatives is a good approach for op because he is in the level of checking injectivity

Comment: Yes i agree, i was just pointing out that $\sqrt x$ send $\mathbb{R}_{+}$ onto itself.